# How do I modify the environment variables of a Kubernetes cluster?

Tags: kubernetes, kubeadm

I created my cluster through `kubeadm`. Before the creation of the cluster I set an environment variable `~/.bashsrc`. The variable I set is `NO_PROXY`. When the cluster is created this variable gets picked up and is applied to all pods.

I now want to add another entry to the `NO_PROXY` but I know that this update won't be picked up automatically by the cluster.

What is the best way to update the environment variables of a kubernetes cluster?

Answer (score 1):

Environment vars at the time of kubeadm init are not deployed to all pods. There are no pods at that time anyway, you have just created a kubemaster.

When you want to put NO_PROXY into pods/deployments you have to do that the usual way with env on the container.

```
   env:
    - name: NODE_NAME
      valueFrom:
        fieldRef:
          fieldPath: spec.nodeName
```

Comment: It's populated to various pods such as the kube-apiserver pod. I had to install cert manager using helm. I was facing a proxy issue, to fix it I had to take down the cluster, change the environment variable, and then start the cluster again. Then initialize the cluster again. There surely has to be a better way.